# Custom Header and Footer not displayed in odoo11

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, odoo, qweb, odoo-11

I'm creating a report in odoo 11 where i want to print repeatable headers and footers. Below is my code to do the same.

**Header Code**

```xml
 <div class="header">
       <img  height="160" src='/module_name/static/src/img/'/>
 </div>
```

**Footer Code**

```xml
<div class="footer">
       <img  height="160" src='/module_name/static/src/img/'/>
 </div
```

And i'm using wkhtmltopdf version - 0.12.4. In this version the custom footer is working properly but the header isn't working.

**Further Research**

- When trying with wkhtmltopdf version - 0.12.1 - In this version the default header was displaying despite overriding the header with custom header
- When trying with wkhtmltopdf version - 0.12.2.2 - In this version no header and footer was displayed (not even the default)
- When trying with wkhtmltopdf version - 0.12.2.4 - In this version no header and footer was displayed (not even the default)

Any help is much appreciated to bring both custom header and footer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: create template for your header and footer and call it using t-call in your report.

Comment: Welcome in the report hell of Odoo :-( so far 0.12.1 has worked very well. Could you please share more code of your report xml?

Comment: I'm using version 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt) for creating reports recommended in some posts. Otherwise, a little more code would be very useful indeed.

Comment: Huge thanks for who are all have given a reply to my post .  It works properly when i'm installing wkhtmltopdf v-0.12.1 and v -0.12.3.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="header">
</div>

please comment the above code technical -> views -> internal_layout

after call to internal_layout like this 

<t t-call="web.internal_layout">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                    <div class="page" style="font-family: 'helvetica'; font-size: 8pt;">
                        <div class="header">
```